# In clang, how to get underlying type of FieldDecl

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using clang lib to write a compiler frontend for some specific functions. When I traverse AST of some code like this:

```
typedef int integer;

struct _s {
    integer i;
    float f;
};
```

I want to get "int" rather than "integer" when I visit feildDecl "integer i;".
Is there any API of clang to get such **underlying type** easily?

Answer (score 0):

getSplitDesugaredType() is what I need. This API **desugar** the type, which means get the underlying type for a **sugared** type